# S.O.T limit of a sequence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Let $a$ be a positive element in a $C^*$ algebra $A\subseteq B(H)$. 
Consider the S.O.T-lim of the sequence $(x+\frac{1}{n}1_{H})^{-1}x$. The limit exists in $B(H)$ since the sequence is monotone increasing bounded sequence of positive elements.
I want to show that the limit is equal to $1_H$. 
I've tried the Dini's uniform convergence theorem (with functional calculus in mind), but the sequence does not converge pointwise to a continuous function. Actually, the convergence is to $0$ at $0$ and $1$ at $(0,\infty)$ on $\sigma(x)\subseteq [0,\infty)$.
Then, I've tried to use Borel functional calculus. However, I'm not sure that I can "forget" the $0$ at zero since it is a set of measure $0$ and claim that it converges to $1$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $x$ has a non-trivial null space, then $\{0\}$ is not a set of measure $0$ when it comes to the Borel spectral measure. $f(x)=(x+\frac{1}{n})^{-1}x$ converges to $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Maybe my guess that the sequence converges to zero is false. Probably the right thing is that it converges to the support projection of $x$, still i don't know how to show it

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $1$ for $x > 0$. So, using the Borel calculus, $f_n(a)$ converges in the s.o.t. to $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(a)$ for any $a \ge 0$. And $\chi_{\{0\}}(a)+\chi_{(0,\infty)}(a)=e$ is the identity. $\chi_{\{0\}}(a)$ is the projection onto the null space of $a$.